# Set a formatted string to a RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

How can I set a formatted string to a RichTextBox control in a way that it shows me the formatted text, not plain text.

string example:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1046{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0   Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}
{\*\generator Riched20 6.3.9600}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\tx568\f0\fs22\lang22 This is an \cf1\ul example\cf0\ulnone\par
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text by using the `RichTextBox.Selection.Load` method with `Rtf` format:

```
var text = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1046{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0   Calibri;}}{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}{\*\generator Riched20 6.3.9600}\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\tx568\f0\fs22\lang22 This is an \cf1\ul example\cf0\ulnone\par}";

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text)))
{
    rtb.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```